# Remove the last X characters of a custom field value

Tags: php, custom-field

[This snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915753/how-can-i-remove-3-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-php) shows us how to remove 3 characters at the end of a string...

```
echo substr($string, 0, -3);
```

I'd like to find a way to use a custom field value as the string. This is what I've tried with no luck...

```
echo substr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "CUSTOMFIELD", true ), 0, -3 );
```

Comment: Is the value actually a string? And did you try putting it into a variable, instead of calling it directly - although this theoretically shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes the custom field value was a phone number. I'm not sure what you mean by putting it into a variable.

Comment: `$cf = (string) get_post_meta($post->ID, "CUSTOMFIELD", true); echo substr($cf, 0, -3);` Let's type cast it to a string and see if that works.

Comment: That works great, would you like to post it as an answer and i'll mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider that you're dealing with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) a *string* related function as the **str** in the function name indicates. That does mean that the parameter `$string` you give actually has to be of the [type `string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php).

[`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) on the other hand does just give you back whatever type you saved in the first place. So it isn't guaranteed that your getting back a string - you have to make sure of that yourself. Which you can do by [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the value, variable you receive.

So far so good, let's put it together:

```
$custom_field = (string) get_post_meta( $post->ID, "CUSTOMFIELD", true ); 
echo substr( $custom_field, 0, -3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string casting ([string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php))

```
$str = (string) get_post_meta($post->ID, "CUSTOMFIELD", true);
echo substr( $str, 0, -3 );
```